# Double summation of matrices as constraints in convex optimization in CVX

Tags: matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I want to implement the following optimization problem from the following paper [*Randomized Gossip Algorithms*, Page 10 Eq 53](http://www.arpitaghosh.com/papers/gossip.pdf):
\begin{align}
\text{minimize} &\qquad  s\\
\text{subject to} & \qquad \begin{cases} W - \mathbf{11}^T/n \preceq sI\\
W = \sum_{i,j=1}^n\frac1n P_{ij}W_{ij}\\
P_{ij}\geq 0,\quad P_{ij}=0\text{ if }\{i,j\}\not\in E\\
\sum_{j} P_{ij} = 1,\quad \forall i
\end{cases}
\end{align}

1. In this problem, $W$, $P$, and $P_{ij}$ are $n\times{n}$ matrices. I would appreciate if you help me with implementing the following constraint in CVX.
   \begin{equation}
   W=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}P_{i,j}W_{i,j}
   \end{equation}
2. Also, in this problem, $E$ is a set of neighbors of a node $i$. Constraint "$P_{ij}=0$ if $\{i,j\}\not\in E$" means that $P_{ij}$ is zero if nodes $i$ and $j$ are not  neighbors.
   Does anyone can help with how to implement this neighborhood relationship?

For $n=3$, `neighbors.xlsx` can look like:

[image: screenshot of neighbors.xlsx]

This means node 1 is neighbor with node 2, node 2 is neighbor with node 1 and 3, and node 3 is neighbor with node2.

I have the written the following piece of code for that in Matlab. It does not work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
cvx_begin sdp
    agt = struct([]);
    neighbors = readcell('neighbors.xlsx');
    N = 2;
    for i = 1:N
      agt(i).neighbors = neighbors{i};
    end
    variable s
    variable P(N,N) symmetric
    variable W_ij(N,N) symmetric
    expression W
    
    minimize (s)
    
subject to     

P(:) >= 0;

    j = 1;
    for i = 1:N
        D =[i,j];
        if ~ismember(D,agt(i).neighbors)
            P(i,j)== 0;
        end
        j = j+1;
    end


    for i = 1:N
        for j = 1:N
            W = P(i,j).*W_ij;
        end    
    end
    W = (1/N).*W;
    W-(1/N)*ones(N,1)*ones(1,N) - s*eye(N) == semidefinite(N);

cvx_end
```

Comment: I think a Matlab forum might be what you are looking for, sorry.

Comment: @DavidRoberts You have a point. I just posted it here in case someone familiar with this optimization concept could help.

Comment: CVX has help forums: http://ask.cvxr.com/

Comment: @Spring no probs. Even so, it's probably a little questionable if it's on-topic, since MathOverflow is for research questions or those that come up in research. It's tricky to place more applied topics, since for them research is often about applying known techniques to a new or novel problem, which is not what the general culture is here. Best of luck!

Comment: @DavidRoberts I apologize if I seemed to disrespect the forum here. I had no intentions to do so.

Comment: @NathanielJohnston Thanks!

Comment: @Spring no disrespect taken! :-) I think the question is well-posed and you are probably quite close to a solution. Many off-topic questions here are "plz answer this textbook/homework question", so this is a pleasant change